# Incorrect redirect using ZOO item with Joomla's native Language Switcher

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, language, multilingual, zoo

I am using the Zoo item component with ZOOlingual and the native Language Switcher. My problem is that when I am on an item detail from a catalog in english, switching in french redirect in french but to the catalog list instead of the detail of the item.

The url of the detail in English is:

```
http://mysite/index.php?option=com_zoo&task=item&item_id=52&Itemid=125&lang=en
```

and when I switch to French, the url is:

```
http://mysite/index.php?option=com_zoo&view=frontpage&layout=frontpage&Itemid=125&lang=fr
```

But it should be:

```
http://mysite/index.php?option=com_zoo&task=item&item_id=52&Itemid=125&lang=fr
```

I notice that I have lost parameters:

1. the id of the item, not the category.
2. the task parameter

Also `view` and `layout` are parameters which shouldn't appear.

Comment: For what it's worth, official Zoolingual demo acts the same way https://demo.zoolanders.com/index.php/en/extensions/zoolingual-demo.

Comment: so, the is no solution ? Changing the parser in the ajax call ? i don't know in which files i can do that.